# jQuery mobile datepicker is not working properly on popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am developing simple demo application to take start date and end date from user using jQuery mobile datepicker and jQuery mobile popup. My problem is that, popup is opening successfully but when I tried to click in "Start Date" text box datepicker calender is opening successfully but next if I clicked on "End Date" its not working... whats is the root cause, I'm not getting... please help me.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>DatePicker Demo</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/jquery.mobile-git.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/jquery.mobile.datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/stylesheets/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/stylesheets/jquery.mobile-git.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/stylesheets/jquery.mobile.datepicker.css">
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#popupDemo" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a" data-transition="pop">Open Popup</a>
  <div data-role="popup" id="popupDemo" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
     <div data-role="content">
        <form>
           <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
              <h3>Date Picker</h3>
                 <input type="text" id="startdate" data-inline="false" data-role="date" placeholder="Start Date">   
                 <input type="text" id="enddate" data-inline="false" data-role="date" placeholder="End Date">
                 <button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check">Save</button>
           </div>
         </form>
       </div>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$('#startdate, #enddate').on("click", function(this){
    $(this).datepicker("destroy");
    $(this).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true, 
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: new Date('2013','01', '01'), 
        maxDate: new Date(),
        //...and other setup lines you need
    });
$(this).datepicker("refresh");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is working code of Date Picker Note that we have to add this js `jquery.ui.datepicker.js`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
          <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
          <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://rawgithub.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper/master/jquery.mobile.datepicker.css" />
          <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
          <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
          <script src = "https://rawgithub.com/jquery/jquery-ui/1-10-stable/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
          <script src = "https://rawgithub.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper/master/jquery.mobile.datepicker.js"></script>
       </head>

       <body>
          <h2>Vipul Datapicker Example</h2>
          <form>
             <input type = "text" data-role = "date">
          </form>
       </body>
    </html>
```

jsfiddle Demo:-

https://jsfiddle.net/vipulg/g41eocs2/